# Looping through squares sequentially

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I have a grid of squares as shown below and I am trying to figure out how to loop through each row (from bottom to top or vice versa), select a random square and simulate a press (scale it down then up). I have created each row as an array of 5 SKShapeNodes with the code below:

Row of Squares:

```
//Row Seven
        for var i = -2; i < 3; i++ {

            firstSquare = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: self.view!.frame.size.width * (1/5), height: self.view!.frame.size.width * (1/5)))
            firstSquare.fillColor = SKColor(hue: 225.0/360.0, saturation: 0.1176, brightness: 0.2667, alpha: 1.0)
            firstSquare.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
            firstSquare.position = CGPoint(
                x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + ((firstSquare.frame.size.width + CGFloat(2)) * CGFloat(i)),
                y: (CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + self.frame.size.height / 4) - (firstSquare.frame.size.width + CGFloat(2)) * CGFloat(6))
            rowSeven.append(firstSquare)
            addChild(firstSquare)

        }
```

Each of the seven rows is added to an array (gameLayers) that holds all the rows.

```
gameLayers = [rowOne, rowTwo, rowThree, rowFour, rowFive, rowSix, rowSeven]
```

I have the following code to loop through the gameLayers Array to and pick eachRow, select a random element and run the animation of a press.

```
private func randomIntergerInRange(low:Int, high: Int) -> Int {
        let randomGeneratedNumber = low + Int(arc4random()) % (high - low);
        return Int(randomGeneratedNumber)
    }

func loopThrough() {

for eachRow in gameLayers {

    let selectedSquare = eachRow[randomIntergerInRange(0, high: eachRow.count)]

    let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(2) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            let scaleDown = SKAction.scaleTo(0.85, duration: 0.3)
            let scaleUp = SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.3)
            let scalingSequence = SKAction.sequence([scaleDown, scaleUp])

            selectedSquare.runAction(scalingSequence)

    }
}

}
```

On trying this out, a square is selected in each row but all of the selected square run the animation simultaneously and not sequentially as I would wish.

Any ideas what could be the cause. I thought the for loop would run the animation for each element sequentially.

[image]

Comment: It's doing what you wrote, but not what you want.

The runAction is executing on all the squares without any delay between squares. Within the call to "loopThrough", you're establishing instructions to be carried out. Think of that as sending a program to the animation system. You are sending instructions for all squares to animate, and THEN it will run that animation - on all squares.

What you really want is to instruct the animation system to execute on only one square at a time.

Then, you'll need to wait until that animation concludes before starting the next one.

Comment: That absolutely makes sense but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to write the code that way. @JVene

Comment: I can only see so much, but....geeze, have to get used to 'enter' closing comments. Key to designing your plan is to realize you may need a timer, or some means of firing a method after each square finishes it's animation. Further, you'll need to retain which square you last scheduled, so you know which square is up next each time the timer fires. Then, when the last square is scheduled, stop firing the timer.

Comment: @JVene Apologies for the lack of closing comments. Thanks for the tips. That led to the solution below. ;).

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem can be used through a recursive loop. After running the animation on a square on one row, call the same function and update the row on with to fire the animation.

```
var selectedRowIndex = 0

    func loopThrough() {
            let rowSelected = gameLayers[selectedRowIndex] //Select a row from the gameLayers


            let selectedNumber = self.randomIntergerInRange(0, high: rowSelected.count)
            let squareSelected = rowSelected[selectedNumber] //Select a square from the selected Row. 

            //Run the animation on that square
            let scaleDown = SKAction.scaleTo(0.9, duration: 0.2)
            let scaleUp = SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.2)
            let scalingSequence = SKAction.sequence([scaleDown,
                    scaleUp])

            squareSelected.runAction(scalingSequence)


            let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(1.3) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

//Delay for 1.3 seconds and call the function again. Increase the index of the selected row to select the next 
                    if self.selectedRowIndex != self.gameLayers.count - 1 {
                        self.selectedRowIndex++
                        self. loopThrough()
                    }
            }
     }
```

Comment: I suggest you use an `SKAction` or two instead of `dispatch_after` because actions 1) pause/resume appropriately when you pause/resume the scene and/or view, 2) response correctly when you change scene's `speed` property, and 3) are synced with Sprite Kit's game loop.

Comment: Thanks @0x141E. Will implement that.